# How to call intuit reconnnect api (OAuth1.0)?

Tags: oauth, intuit-partner-platform

I am working on intuit integration on my application. Now, I am facing one issue regarding to calling reconnect api of intuit. I am following this reference:  http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/

I am trying with this code::

```
Base64Encoder baseEncoder = Base64Encoder.getInstance();
            Intuit intuit = IntuitLocalServiceUtil.getIntuit();// this is object, which stores the oauth Token and Oauth token secret. 
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/connection/reconnect");
            StringBuilder headerReq = new StringBuilder();
            headerReq.append("OAuth ");
            headerReq.append("oauth_token=\"").append(intuit.getOauthToken()).append("\"");
            headerReq.append(", oauth_consumer_key=\"").append(CommonConstants.INTUIT_QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY).append("\"");
            headerReq.append(", oauth_signature_method=\"base64\"");
            headerReq.append(", oauth_signature=\"")
                    .append(baseEncoder.encode(PropsUtil.get(CommonConstants.INTUIT_QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET).getBytes()))
                    .append(baseEncoder.encode("&".getBytes()))
                    .append(baseEncoder.encode(symmetricEncrypter.decryptData(intuit.getOauthTokenSecret()).getBytes())).append("\"");

            headerReq.append(", oauth_version=\"1.0\"");
            httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", headerReq.toString());
            System.out.println("Header Rwquesssssssssssst::::::" + headerReq.toString());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            try {
                System.out.println("Responsee::"+ response.getStatusLine());
}
```

And every time I am getting this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PlatformResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://platform.intuit.com/api/v1">
  <ErrorMessage>This API requires Authorization.</ErrorMessage>
  <ErrorCode>22</ErrorCode>
  <ServerTime>2014-08-16T18:15:45.6417185Z</ServerTime>
</PlatformResponse>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PlatformResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://platform.intuit.com/api/v1">
  <ErrorMessage>Authentication required</ErrorMessage>
  <ErrorCode>22</ErrorCode>
  <ServerTime>2014-08-16T18:15:47.3382208Z</ServerTime>
</PlatformResponse>
```

I did test same thing using postman, but I got same type of error on response. 
I am sure that, my key are valid and they are working right now.

(PS: I know that, those key can be regenerated only within 150 to 180 days but I was expecting window bound exception for intuit api but I am not getting those type of valid errors, I am only getting authentication error.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is solved by using SignPost because JAVA devkit of Inuit have a bug.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;
import oauth.signpost.signature.AuthorizationHeaderSigningStrategy;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import com.intuit.ipp.data.Account;
import com.intuit.ipp.exception.FMSException;
import com.intuit.ipp.net.MethodType;
import com.intuit.ipp.services.DataService;

public class POCWithoutDevkitTest {

    private DataService service;
    private OAuthConsumer oAuthConsumer;
    private static String realmID = null;

    public POCWithoutDevkitTest() {
        realmID = "122294642099";
        String consumerKey = "AAAAA";
        String consumerSecret = "BBBBB";
        String accessToken = "CCCCC";
        String accessTokenSecret = "DDDDD";

        setupContext(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
    }

    public void setupContext(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String accessToken, String accessTokenSecret) {
            this.oAuthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
            oAuthConsumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
            oAuthConsumer.setSigningStrategy(new AuthorizationHeaderSigningStrategy());
    }

    public void authorize(HttpRequestBase httpRequest) throws FMSException {
        try {
            oAuthConsumer.sign(httpRequest);
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            throw new FMSException(e);
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            throw new FMSException(e);
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            throw new FMSException(e);
        }
    }

    public void executeGetRequest(String customURIString){
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", "UTF-8");

        HttpRequestBase httpRequest = null;
        URI uri = null;

        try {
            uri = new URI(customURIString);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String methodtype = "GET";

        if (methodtype.equals(MethodType.GET.toString())) {
            httpRequest = new HttpGet(uri);
        }

        httpRequest.addHeader("content-type", "application/xml");
        httpRequest.addHeader("Accept","application/xml");

        try {
            authorize(httpRequest);
        } catch (FMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            HttpHost target = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), -1, uri.getScheme());
            httpResponse = client.execute(target, httpRequest);
            System.out.println("Connection status : " + httpResponse.getStatusLine());

            InputStream inputStraem = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(inputStraem, writer, "UTF-8");
            String output = writer.toString();

            System.out.println(output);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        POCWithoutDevkitTest withoutDevkitClient = new POCWithoutDevkitTest();
        withoutDevkitClient.executeGetRequest("https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/connection/reconnect");
    }

}
```

And dependency is:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
        <artifactId>signpost-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
        <artifactId>signpost-commonshttp4</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hey Sanjay,
It is better to give credit to the original poster of your qts. Isn't it ? Why are you coping post from other thread and posting it as ans ? 
If you want please refer the link in your answer or in comment. Thanks

Comment: @Sanjaya Pandey Could you please provide some code for callback concept for get new key from intuit.

Comment: hi @Ram This code works which is provided by intuit developer supports. Can you tell me what kind of error you are facing? Hope, I can solve your problem.

Comment: @Sanjaya Pandey, I want to get all the key during run time and I will send the key to the function setupContext(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret). Where and how to get the key?.please guide me

Comment: I had implemented this token renewable code successfully during run time.  Can you post response of reconnect api?

Answer (score 1):

Which SDK are you using?
For PHP, you can refer to this sample-
https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/8292870

For dotnet- use dev defined call-
Example of a dev defined call-https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/0913b4c224de758fde0a

Similarly you can call the Platform service

Refer-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/oauth_management_api#Reconnect

Please find instructions below for creating short-lived OAuth tokens to test Reconnect.

1. Navigate to IPP Playground- Go to Manage My Apps->Click on your app

Fill in consumer key and consumer secret in links below.

Prod: https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA/?ck=<>&cs=<>

Alternatively, you can navigate to the Manage page for your app on stage or prod and click ‘Test connect to app (OAuth)’.

1. Enter the duration you would like for the issued OAuth tokens (e.g., 3600 for successful Reconnect) in the ‘Access Token Duration’ field. Screen shot attached.
2. Click on the Connect to QuickBooks button, go through OAuth flow to authorize a connection to a realm.
3. Under the resulting Post-Connection Interactions heading, click ‘Reconnect API Test’.
4. A new page will launch where your OAuth tokens are displayed. Copy these values to your application to test Reconnect.

Comment: I am using java. Do we have sample code for java? I didn't get any reason behind getting <ErrorMessage>This API requires Authorization.</ErrorMessage> . It should return <ErrorMessage>Token Refresh Window Out of Bounds</ErrorMessage>.

Comment: Postman and other rest clients do not generate the same signature format as required by IPP apis. Therefore, you are getting signature invalid error. Please double percent encode your call back url for generating oauth tokens to generate the correct signature format. That's the best I can suggest as I do not have the java sample code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have been stuck on this problem since 3 days, I follow the Oauth1.0 standard but I can't connect successfully. I don't have callback url and I should able to get those tokens on response. As you mentioned, They have sample code for c# and for php but don't have for java. I did ask same question on ipp community but it is still unanswered. :(

Comment: See this example here on IPP community for getting oauth tokens. You can compare the raw xmls for your library with the example I have shared here-https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/970451-reading-report-gives-applicationauthenticationfailed?jump_to=comment_2178310

Comment: Please see that we answer questions on both SO and Live Community. Since, your question is being answered here, there will not be separate tracking a second time there too. :)

Comment: Can we store verifierCode on our data? If yes then I can retrieve via IAPlatformClient. When does this code change? Can I use previously stored verifierCode after reconnect success? 
My code will be: pClient.getOAuthAccessToken(verifierCode, requestToken, requestTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret) and I will get request token using: Map<String, String> keys = pClient.getRequestTokenAndSecret(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
Am I right?

Comment: Verifiercode is unique for each connect request. Please read docs- sec 6.2.3